# Binding ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I have a ListView with the following code:

```
<ListView Name="ListView1">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="File" Width="60">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Width="28" Height="28" Source="{Binding Icon}" Name="img"/>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding File}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Password" Width="150">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Width="145" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Can someone tell me how can I add items in it during run time and set all the bindings (Icon,File,Type)?

Comment: If your question has nothing to do with Visual-Studio then don't tag it as such...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a class like:

```
class MyData 
{
    public string File { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }  // a path to an Icon
    ...
}
```

and then you use (in for example Window_Loaded) an

```
  ObservableCollection<MyData> data = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
  listView1.Items = data;
  data.Add(new MyData { File="text", ... });
```