# What's the quickest and easiest way to add items in a ListView that has multiple columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, binding

I have a ListView called lv with three columns. What's the quickest and easiest way to add items in it during runtime? I am using WPF.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835220/binding-listview)

Comment: We've been here before. Don't program against Controls. Bind them to a List and add your items to that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ListView 
        x:Name="lv" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}">

        <ListView.View>
        <GridView >
            <GridViewColumn Header="Header1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Prop1}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Header2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Prop2}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Header3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Prop3}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

</ListView>
```

In your ViewModel you should have some collection, like this:

```
  public ObservableCollection<Test> Items { get; protected set; }
```

where Test is :

```
public class Test
{
    public int Prop1{ get; set; }
    public String Prop2{ get; set; }
    public int Prop3{ get; set; }
}
```

When you will put/remove data in this "Items" Property, ListView will update itself automaticly.

Comment: Why you wonna modify the binding path?

Comment: You could realize INotifyPropertyChanged interface in 'public class Test' then change Prop1 setteg to somth like this: set { _data = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Prop1"); } You can read about this in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx and do the same ;)