# Add more than one item in a list view

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listview

I'm doing a program that i need to insert two items in the same line of the list view.
That's the XAML code:

```
<ListView Height="486" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="lvTimeline" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="260">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" MaxHeight="48" MaxWidth="48" />
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="250" Margin="2,0,2,0" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="14"  />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I have tried infinity ways to do that, but nothing work. What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by two items in the same line? (By the way, `ListViews` should use the [`View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.view.aspx), if you don't need that use a `ListBox`)

Comment: look at this StackOverFlow post and see if it helps to give you an Idea.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855833/whats-the-quickest-and-easiest-way-to-add-items-in-a-listview-that-has-multiple

Comment: You can use a listbox w/ a data template. the data template can have the two items.

Answer (score 1):

The ListView needs an ItemsSource then you bind the Path on the two items.  And you can also create columns with a GridView.  I like GridView because it sizes columns with headers.